# Groovy Cannot Resolve Static Class

Tags: groovy

I have the following Groovy script as `test.groovy`:

```
import test.Vehicle

def ok=new Vehicle();
def test=new Vehicle.Deserializer();

println "Hello, world!"
```

And, I have `code/test/Vehicle.groovy`, with the following class definition:

```
package test;

public class Vehicle {
  public static class Deserializer {
  }
}
```

However, the following command fails:

```
groovy -cp code/ test.groovy
```

(`groovy -v` reports 2.4.7)

I would expect it to succeed and print "Hello, world". Instead, I get:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/tmp/test.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class Vehicle.Deserializer 
 @ line 4, column 10.
   def test=new Vehicle.Deserializer();
            ^

1 error
```

Since the script is not failing on the prior line, Groovy is finding the `Vehicle` class without issue. It is just not finding the `Deserializer` static class.

However, this script works just fine:

```
public class Vehicle {
  public static class Deserializer {
  }
}

def ok=new Vehicle();
def test=new Vehicle.Deserializer();

println "Hello, world!"
```

Is there something that I need to be doing to allow Groovy to work with static classes, when the static class (and its outer class) are defined in a separate Groovy file?

---

**UPDATE**: I found [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4267) and can confirm that Groovy can at least sort of see the `Deserializer` class:

```
import test.Vehicle;
import static test.Vehicle.Deserializer;

println Deserializer.class.name

def ok=new Vehicle();
// def test=new Vehicle.Deserializer();

println "Hello, world!"
```

This works as expected:

```
test.Vehicle$Deserializer
Hello, world!
```

However, uncommenting the `def test=new Vehicle.Deserializer();` still gives me the error, as does changing that to `def test=new Deserializer();` (given the `import static`).

Comment: I have not tested myself but have you tried importing the static class explicitly as well in `test.groovy` as `import static test.Vehicle.Deserializer` ?

Comment: @dmahapatro: `import test.Vehicle.Deserializer` results in a second "unable to resolve class" error, pointing at that line. `import static test.Vehicle.Deserializer`, strangely, does *not* cause a second error, but it does not clear up the first one.

Comment: Yes, witnessed the same. I was also trying to compile `Vehicle.groovy` by `groovyc` before executing `test.groovy`, but I still see it complaining. It may be an issue.

Comment: Having `test.groovy` in the same package as `Vehicle.groovy`, compiling `Vehicle.groovy` and then running `groovy test.groovy` works!!

Comment: @dmahapatro: I am not sure what "alongside" means. If you mean "not in a package, like the `test` that I am using", that is not an option in my case, and that resembles my working script (last code snippet in the question).

Comment: Updated above comment to say "in the same package as"

Comment: @dmahapatro: I just added a `package test` line to the top of the first script from my question. I still get the same error message. Is there something more to putting a non-class Groovy script in a package?

Comment: You need to compile `Vehicle.groovy` by using `groovyc Vehicle.groovy`, after which it should work. It worked for me.

Comment: @dmahapatro: I am trying to use Groovy in interpreted mode, not compiled mode. But, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [a known Groovy bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7812). If your static class has a zero-arguments constructor, you can work around this via `newInstance()`:

```
import test.Vehicle;
import static test.Vehicle.Deserializer;

def ok=new Vehicle();
def test=Deserializer.class.newInstance();

println "Hello, world!"
```